# vba excel conditional formatting - invalid Procedure call or argument

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet in which I want to add an Conditional Formula by VBA. While I'm trying to do so, Excel is throwing "Invalid procedure call or argument" and I can't find why.

The problem is with exactly this line:

```
Set cf = shG.Range("E" & (i - 3) & ":AI" & (i - 2)).FormatConditions.Add(type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""holiday"",E$" & i & ")),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""l4"",E$" & i & ")))")
```

What it should do?

> It should change font color to white for 1st and 2nd rows in case if 4th row will contain "holiday" or "l4"

Full Sub:

```
Sub AddCondForm(shG As Worksheet)
    Dim r As Range
    Dim cf
    Set r = shRoles.Cells(2, 1)
    Do
        For i = 8 To 204 Step 4
            If Not IsEmpty(shRoles.Cells(r.row, 2)) Then
                Set cf = shG.Range("E" & i & ":AI" & i).FormatConditions.Add(type:=xlTextString, String:=r.Value, _
                TextOperator:=xlBeginsWith)
            Else
                Set cf = shG.Range("E" & i & ":AI" & i).FormatConditions.Add(type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
                Formula1:=r.Value)
            End If
            cf.Interior.Color = r.Next.Next.Next.Interior.Color
            cf.Font.Color = r.Next.Next.Next.Font.Color
            cf.SetFirstPriority

'HERE IS PROBLEM

            Set cf = shG.Range("E" & (i - 3) & ":AI" & (i - 2)).FormatConditions.Add(type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""holiday"",E$" & i & ")),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""l4"",E$" & i & ")))")

'END OF PROBLEM
                cf.Font.ColorIndex = 2 
                'Coloring C Column 
                Set cf = shG.Range("C" & (i - 3) & ":C" & i).FormatConditions.Add(type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A$" & i - 3 & "=1")
                cf.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                Set cf = shG.Range("C" & (i - 3) & ":C" & i).FormatConditions.Add(type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A$" & i - 3 & "=3/4")
                cf.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                cf.Interior.TintAndShade = 0.2
                Set cf = shG.Range("C" & (i - 3) & ":C" & i).FormatConditions.Add(type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A$" & i - 3 & "=1/2")
                cf.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                cf.Interior.TintAndShade = 0.4
                Set cf = shG.Range("C" & (i - 3) & ":C" & i).FormatConditions.Add(type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A$" & i - 3 & "=1/4")
                cf.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                cf.Interior.TintAndShade = 0.6
            Next
            Set r = shRoles.Cells(r.row + 1, 1)
        Loop Until IsEmpty(r.Value)
    End Sub
```

PS. I checked the formula itself and it seems working properly. Other lines are also working well. Only this one and I don't know why :'(

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I understand. 
The formula itself is String. After simplifying it's:

`formula = "=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""holiday"", E$" & i & ")), ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""L4"", E$" & i & ")))"`

and
`Set cf = shG.Range(textAddress).FormatConditions.Add(type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formula)`

I don't see where is error :/

Comment: Sometimes it helps to create a helper column where you paste the formula to be used by format condition. Put the formula in row 5 referring to E8

Comment: What you could try to see if the syntax of the formula is the issue? I.e. use a much simpler formula as the start/initial case and see if that generates an error. If so you need to look elsewhere. If not you can step by step make your formula more complex until you have the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not English user, this may be important for you.

In case of `FormatCondition.Add` you need to add formula exactly the same as if you were entering it manually. So if separator in your language is not a comma, like in Poland (we have semicolon) you would have to use that separator and translate your formulas to that language.

In my case it means I had to change formula to

```
=LUB(CZY.LICZBA(SZUKAJ.TEKST(""holiday"";E$" & i & "));CZY.LICZBA(SZUKAJ.TEKST(""l4"";E$" & i & ")))"
```